# Show categories not in gallery post format

Tags: wordpress

I want to show all blog categories that aren't of type gallery. My code almost works but if I have 2 posts in the same category the category is shown twice ie:

If I create a category called 'news' and add 2 non-gallery posts, it shows up as:

> ```
> news
> news
> ```

instead of just

> ```
> news
> ```

```
<?php 
   $galleryPosts = new WP_Query(array(
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'order' => 'ASC'
   ));
   ?>
<?php if ( $galleryPosts->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $galleryPosts->have_posts() ) : $galleryPosts->the_post(); ?>
<?php if(!has_post_format('gallery')) {
   the_category();
   }

   ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, in your code the category will be displayed for non-gallery posts. Is that causing a problem?

Comment: No, that is what I want. I only want to show non gallery posts. But the problem is that category names are showing up as many times as I have posts for that category.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress non-gallery posts, try selecting only those posts initially and then remove the `has_post_format('gallery')` check:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(                
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 
                    'post-format-gallery'
                ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Then in PHP:

```
if ($posts->have_posts()) {
    while ($posts->have_posts()) {
        $posts->the_post();
        the_category();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. That puts the page in an infinite loop?

Comment: The gallery posts can be removed in the initial query.

Comment: Thanks again, but getting an error now. Cannot use object of type WP_Query as array

Comment: thank you. That still gives me duplicate categories unfortunately

Comment: Oh OK, sounds like you want one post per category?

Comment: Try these options for retrieving the top categories, and then getting a post for each category: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274405/get-5-most-recent-categories https://www.idiotinside.com/2015/10/31/get-top-categories-wordpress/

Comment: I want to list the categories only for the gallery post format. But it should show the category name only once. If I have 2 posts, it shows the category name 2 times. If I have 3 posts, it shows that category name 3 times etc.